# I can't change server connection using SQLCMD in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, sqlcmd

I want to easily/quickly change the server connection (many times) inside a Script

Then I enable the SQLCMD mode and added the following:

```
:CONNECT MYSERVER -U myUser -P myPassword
USE [NewDatabase]
GO
```

But when I execute this query I get the following output:

> Connecting to MYSERVER as MYUSER...
>
> Disconnecting connection from MYSERVER as MYUSER...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Many of the possible answers are based on what the rest of the query looks like. I suspect that this is a misuse of the GO batch separator. If GO is missing, and you connect to different servers in a script, all of the queries go to the final connection mentioned in the script.

In this case, your use of GO, especially if there are other CONNECT commands in the script, probably result in the script section running against another connection.  Note that I couldn't decide whether GO in a batch actually disconnects the script, so I ran a test. No, the GO does not simply disconnect the script from the connection. However, if you have another CONNECT statement before the next GO, the commands in between are executed in the last CONNECT executed before the next GO, or the end of the script, whichever comes first.

This worked fine:

```
:CONNECT Server1
USE MyDB

SELECT DB_Name()    -- Returned MyDB
GO
:CONNECT YourServer
Use DB13

SELECT DB_Name()    -- Returned DB13
GO
```

However, this did not:

```
:CONNECT Server1
USE MyDB

SELECT DB_Name()    -- Returned DB13
-- No GO statement here
:CONNECT YourServer
Use DB13

SELECT DB_Name()    -- Returned DB13
GO
```

Since you don't actually need a GO after a `USE` statement, remove it there. Instead, place a GO before each CONNECT statement.

Oh, and just in case - if all you have in your query is what you have in your example above, you will only receive the messages you see. When the query ends, you are disconnected from the server specified in the CONNECT statement.